# Performence Java Multithreading, create new Object or use sychronized

Tags: java, multithreading, server

I have a server with multithreading.
Each connection has it's own thread. The thread sometimes needs to access some methods from an Object and the method could be only called once at a time. So what would be better for the performance: Just to create a new object for every thread when it need to use it. Or sharing one global object which has synchronized methods?

Comment: The reason one isn't definitively better than the other is because it depends on the situation.

Comment: how much overhead is there in this object? How long do calls to this object take? How many threads will access it? Each "connection" to what has it's own thread, a DB? What does that connection have to do with the object? Need more context to help.

Comment: -The Object is very small, its just connect to FCM (Google Firebase Messaging)
-Its sending fast some data to the server(1,5 to 2 Seconds)
-I dont know how many connections my server will handle, max. 1000 an hour of this type.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`synchronizing` would not lead you to better performance. It could potentially make the performance worse if done incorrectly.
You are not showing any code so there is no way for us to give you any advice on what to focus on optimizing.
As a general advice:
1) Avoid any state if possible. This way synchronized is not needed
2) Make state immutable if the object needs to have a state. This way you don't care about synchronizing and avoid tedious bugs
3) If object creation is cheap then just do that using (2) if possible
4) If object creation is heavy look into singleton pattern and try to use locks on the methods.

And about

> Each connection have its own Thread

Make sure you use a thread pool